# Imagemagick convert works from console but not in Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, sidekiq

I have a model with a paperclip attachment (image or pdf file). I'm processing this model in a background process with Sidekiq. In the background process I'm converting the pdf file into a pdf file string with imagemagick convert function in order to get rid of any password protection or garbage in the file format.

This convert works well in my development environment's sidekiq and on my staging server's sidekiq but it is not working on production server's sidekiq. On my production server it is working if I run the converting method from Rails console. When it is not working the `dst` file is empty and the returned string is `''`

The model looks like this

```
class Receipt < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_attached_file :image, styles: { original: {} }, path: ':rails_root/attachments/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename'

  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => IMAGE_MIME_TYPES

  def convert_pdf_to_pdf_string
    if %w(application/pdf application/octet-stream).include?(image.content_type)
      begin
        dst = Tempfile.new([File.basename(image.path, File.extname(image.path)), '.pdf'], :encoding => 'ascii-8bit')
        dst.flush
        `convert -density 200 #{image.path.shellescape} #{dst.path.shellescape}`
        dst
        str = File.open(dst.path, 'rb') {|f| f.read}.to_s
      ensure
        dst.close
        dst.unlink
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I'm out of ideas how to debug this problem.

There is no exceptions raised. I also tried to log the return value of the backticks call but that doesn't return anything.

Please throw any ideas what I should check.

Comment: Are you using Heroku for this(production server)?

Comment: No, it is a Debian server. And the staging and production servers should be configured the same way.

Comment: Use something like pry-remote, put a breakpoint, and check what's up.

Answer (score 1):

I started to figure out how to make the `convert` to produce some logging. After I changed the backticks call to

```
`convert -density 200 #{image.path.shellescape} #{dst.path.shellescape} 2>log/magick_error.log 1>log/magick.log`
```

the code started to work. Into the magick_error.log it produces

```
    **** Warning: File has some garbage before %PDF- .
```

So I guess this output to STDERR was some how screwing up things in my production environment. Staging and development environments were tolerating that.